# Download FireStorage files using gsutil

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am trying to download all files to my system from my firestorage using gsutil.

I am using the following command as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to download all .jpg files:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/*.jpg
```

however I am getting the error saying that the cp command has the wrong number of arguments I suppose its asking for a path in my computer, but how do I put that there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `gsutil cp` is:

```
gsutil cp <source> <destination>
```

You're calling it as:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/*.jpg
```

This means that you're specifying a source, but not a destination. If you want to for example store the files in the directory/folder where you run the command, you would run it as:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/*.jpg .
```

The `.` at the end there means that the destination is the current directory, where you run the command.

Comment: I see how do I specify my local storage as the destination?? and my bucket looks like this `gs://mybucket/File/Path One`.
so do I give the space there or do I write `gs://mybucket/File/ Path%20%One`

Comment: The `.` is the local directory on the machine where you run `gsutil`. If you run that local you local machine, the files are put into the directory where you run the command.

Comment: sorry guys I missed the `.` in the docs and in this comment.  Thanks alot. I was multitasking skimming through , honestly it feels embarassing..

Answer (score 1):

Please go back and check well, it is suppossed to work fine.

`gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/*.txt .`